# Match a Square Bracket in grep Without Regex

Tags: linux, grep

The follow grep command returns ZERO matches:

```
grep -Filr "$dif_refund[0]->{ $a[" /var/www/html/
```

However, if I just remove the square bracket, several matching filenames are returned:

```
grep -Filr "$dif_refund[0]->{ $a" /var/www/html/
```

How can I make my search work with square brackets without using a regular expression?

Comment: `grep -Filr "$dif_refund[0]->{ $a\" /var/www/html/` has unclosed `"`, it would be a syntax error from shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace your double-quotes w/ single-quotes.
The problem is not the square bracket, the problem is the `$a`

```
grep -Filr '$dif_refund[0]->{ $a[' /var/www/html/
```

Comment: ... and, somewhat, the `$dif_refund`.

Comment: Why do double-quotes cause a problem? The reason I like using them is because I often search for strings likeso: grep -Filr "$php_array[ 0 ] = 'Hello, world!'" /var/www/html/
How would I search for such a string initialized with single quotes?

Comment: Because they allow the shell to expand variables. And in your environment the variable `$a` most likely doesn't contain the value **$a**, which then means that you're grepping for `{ [`. @GTSJoe

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, it makes total sense now. Answer accepted and up-voted.

Comment: Cheers ... and grepping for a string w/ embedded single quotes is slightly more complicated (very ugly, actually ;)) ... `grep -Filr '$php_array[ 0 ] = '"'"'Hello, world!'"'"'' /var/www/html/` ... HIH.   @GTSJoe

Comment: **Or** you could keep the double quotes but escape the `$` ... `grep -Filr "\$dif_refund[0]->{ \$a[" /var/www/html/`

Comment: I like the second suggestion about just escaping dollar signs with a backslash--much cleaner! =)